# Probability of winning a two player first to three game of rock paper scissors

Tags: probability

The first player (out of the two) to win three games, wins.

My naive answer is 1/2, is this correct?

I think of each game indepedently. There are three possible outcomes, p1 wins (1/3), p2 wins (1/3), tie (1/3). Since a tie warrants another game, and there is no limit on games, I'd imagine the tie scenario recursively devolves to p1 wins (1/6), p2 wins (1/6), which maybe might be provable by induction.

So in the end, each player has a 1/2 chance of winning. Is this correct?

Comment: the plays have equal probability of winning, so that's true by symmetry

Comment: You can think of this game as an absorbing Markov chain with two absorbing states if you want to prove your assertions.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Empirically, these games are not really independent; there is dependence in the strategies people use, biases, etc. And scissors has a higher proportion of wins.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we shall assume that the process is entirely random, with no skill/intuition playing a part

Secondly, I shall solve for first to two wins, and leave it to you to extend the same process for first to three wins.

---

Focus on player **A** and label **states** as $S, W_1,W_2,L_1,L_2$ for start, first win, second win, first loss and second loss respectively.

The state equations for **A** are then

$\displaylines {S = \frac{S}{3} +\frac{W_1}{3} + \frac{L_1}{3} \;\;...[I]\\
W_1 = \frac{W_1}{3} +\frac{L_1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \times 1 \;\;...[II]\\ L_1 = \frac{L_1}{3} +\frac{W_1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \times 0\;\;...[III]}$

The last term in [II] indicates that **A** has finally won,
and the last term in [III] indicates that **A** doesn't lose

As expected, solving the equations gives $S = \dfrac12$ as the winning probability of **A** from starting state